# Максимальный размер apk в GooglePlay

Tags: android, google-play

Подскажите, есть ли ограничения для размера `apk` файла в `GooglePlay`? И если есть, то какие?

Comment: не уверен насчет сейчас, но раньше было 50 МБ. Если больше 50, то надо было разбивать на несколько файлов

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Поддержка Гугл](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en) говорит, что для android 2.2 и ниже - **50mb**; для 2.3 и выше - **100mb**

> APK file sizes
>   APK files have a maximum file size, based on the Android version your APK supports. If you can't support all devices with a single APK, you can upload multiple APKs using the same app listing that target different device configurations.
>
> 100MB - APKs that target Android 2.3 and higher (API level 9-10 and 14+)
>
> 50MB - APKs that target Android 2.2 and lower (API level 8 or lower)
>
> Tip: Users must run Play Store version 5.2 or higher to install 100MB APKs.